# Visual Studio 2008 - Won't Enter Debug Mode or Load ASP.NET Web Application

Tags: visual-studio-2008, asp.net-mvc-2, visual-studio-debugging

I've been doing development all morning, and now all of a sudden, when I hit F5 to load up the ASP.NET web application from inside my Visual Studio, the web application never successfully loads, and I am unable to enter debug mode.

I set a breakpoint in my application's Global.asax file in order to see if it's crashing, and I'm getting the "empty circle" on the left side of the line for the breakpoint.  When I mouse over the breakpoint, I see a tooltip that says "The breakpoint will not be hit.  No symbols have been loaded for this document."

What could I have possibly done to cause this?

Thanks.

EDIT - Furthermore, when I actually run in debug mode and open the Debug -> Windows -> Modules window I do not even see any of my .dlls in the list of modules.

Comment: Did you try ReBuilding the proj?

Comment: Yes, I've done a clean and rebuild several times.  The .dll files for my web application are not even being loaded into the debug modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is I had to delete this folder's contents:

C:/Users/Adam/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/